# Mapped drive is accessed drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012

I've got some users that will randomly get 'Access Denied' when trying to access a mapped drive or print to a shared printer. When i get the users to 'log-off-Log-on' they are able to access the shares and printers.

Initially i was thinking that the issue was due to permissions set on the folders but they have the same permissions as myself.

The PDC is 'Server1' and has DC and Print roles installed. 'Server2' is our file server.
'User1' and 'User2' have the problem with accessing the shares/printer. Both of these users are members of a OU named 'DEV' and 'ALL_COMPANY'.
The user that i login as is members of 'IT_TEAM' and 'ALL_COMPANY', aswell as the default 'DomainAdmins'.

The folder on Server2 is named 'FOLDER' and has been shared to the OUs IT_TEAM and DEV. Both Groups have R+W access to this folder.

So far, the only solution i have found is to restart the PC.

Comment: The problem with your question is that it's simply too vague and could be dozens of different things.  Can you check the security event log on the server (make sure security auditing is enabled)?  If you kill the mappings via a cmd prompt and then re-add them does that work instead of logoff/logon?

Comment: @TheCleaner
I've checked the event logs and nothing stands out, both on the local PC or the server the drive points to.

I disconnected and re-added the drives using a bat file but get the below.
http://imgur.com/wyCv6DM

If i kill all the drives, restart and run the same BATCH script, all drives connect successfully.

Comment: Based on your image it looks like what I was thinking.  It seems like you have multiple account logins to that same remote server from the same user profile on the local PC.  When it isn't working, do a `net use` from the cmd prompt and post the output here.  Your error shows that you are trying to connect to the remote file server with the two different sets of credentials.  It's possible there's another login script or gpo or other mapped drive locally that was calling a different username/pwd than what you are attempting in your batch file.